# Python 2.7.6 dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, naming-conventions

I'm having a bit of trouble with Python 2.7.6, getting information from a dictionary and doing something useful with it. I have attached my entire code below, as I'm not sure what specifically is wrong, it might not be something I'm expecting.

I am trying to generate some test data; a bunch of randomly distributed sources (1's) across an image that move a small amount from their correct positions. I track each source individually using dictionaries, and use dictionaries within a dictionary for each image containing shifted sources.

My problem is when I want to take the average motion of the sources within an image. I have made the spot I believe the problem to be in clear (about halfway down). I have left in a few different techniques I have tried, they are commented out. Currently I am only using 3 images, but I intend to increase this number significantly. If I was sticking to only 3, I would have gone with a different method and written a lot of this out the long way.

I've had a look for other questions like this but have not found anything specific to my issue, which could be because I don't know the lingo for what it is I am trying to do. Apologies if this has been asked before and solved.

```
# Source position-offset tracker

import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import copy
import random
from pylab import boxplot

 #FUNCTIONS


def random_movement(source_positions):
    source_positions_changed={}
    for n in range(len(source_positions)): # n = [0,1]
        key = source_positions.keys()[n]
        del_x = source_positions[key][0]+random.randint(0,1)
        del_y = source_positions[key][1]+random.randint(0,1)
        source_positions_changed[key] = (del_x,del_y)
    return source_positions_changed

 #OTHER CODE

 # put in original positions
 # -> randomly distributed
 # -> of values 0 or 1 only

original_positions = np.random.randint(2,size=(10,10))



 # Tag each source within the image to keep track of them
source_positions = {}
source_count=0
for x in range(len(original_positions)):
    for y in range(len(original_positions[0])):
        if original_positions[x,y] == 1: # finding all sources
            source_count += 1
            index = 'S'+str(source_count)
            source_positions[index] = (x,y) 
                    # attach a source name to its position

source_numbers = len(source_positions)
number_timesteps = 2 # how many images were taken NOT including the original

 # create a dictionary for the timesteps of shifted sources
 # timesteps are the images where the sources have moves from the correct position
dictionary = {}
for x in range(1,number_timesteps+1):
    #exec('dictionary%s = copy.copy(random_movement(source_positions))'%x)
    dictionary['position_changed{0}'.format(x)] = copy.copy(random_movement(source_positions))


 # finding the distances from the sources original positions
 #source_distance_sum = {}

#################################################
### THIS IS WHERE I THINK I'M HAVING PROBLEMS ###
#################################################

# this should take make the motion of any sources that appear outside the range of the image -1
# and for sources that remain in range should find the motion from the correct position
# using equation: a^2 = b^2 + c^2
# should end up with source_distance_sum1 and source_distance_sum2 that have the motions from the correct positions of each source for the images, whose positional information was stored in dictionary['position_changed1'] and dictionary['position_changed2'] respectively
 #source_distance_sum=[]
#distance_moved=[]
for source in range(1,source_numbers+1):
    #source_distance_sum['S{0}'.format(source)]=0
    for tstep in range(1,number_timesteps+1):
        exec('source_distance_sum%s=[]'%tstep)
        if dictionary['position_changed{0}'.format(tstep)]['S{0}'.format(source)][0]>=len(original_positions) or dictionary['position_changed{0}'.format(tstep)]['S{0}'.format(source)][1]>=len(original_positions[0]):
        #if 'dictionary%s[S%s][0]>=len(original_positions) or dictionary%s[S%s][1]>=len(original_positions[0])'%(tstep,source,tstep,source)
            #source_distance_sum['S{0}'.format(source)]=-1
            exec('source_distance_sum%s.append(-1)'%tstep)
            #print 'if 1: '+str(source_distance_sum1)
            #print 'if 2: '+str(source_distance_sum2)
        # dealing with sources moved out of range
        else:
            distance_moved=np.sqrt((source_positions['S{0}'.format(source)][0]-dictionary['position_changed{0}'.format(tstep)]['S{0}'.format(source)][0])**2+(source_positions['S{0}'.format(source)][1]-dictionary['position_changed{0}'.format(tstep)]['S{0}'.format(source)][1])**2)
# I have tried changing distance_moved as well, in similar ways to source_distance_sum, but I have as yet had no luck. 
            #source_distance_sum['S{0}'.format(source)]=distance_moved
            exec('source_distance_sum%s.append(distance_moved)'%tstep)
# why does this not work!!!!????? I really feel like it should...
        # for movement that stays in range
            #print 'else 1: '+str(source_distance_sum1)
            #print 'else 2: '+str(source_distance_sum2)

# then I want to use the information from the source_distance_sum1 & 2 and find the averages. I realise the following code will not work, but I cannot get the previous paragraph to work, so have not moved on to fixing the following. 
 # average distance:
source_distance = []
for source in range(1,len(source_distance_sum)+1):
    if source_distance_sum['S{0}'.format(source)] > -1:
        source_distance.append(source_distance_sum['S{0}'.format(source)])

average = sum(source_distance)/float(len(source_distance))

 # set range of graph 
 #axx_max = np.ceil(max(distance_travelled))
 #axy_max = np.ceil(max(number_of_sources))

 # plot graph
fig = plt.figure()
 #plt.axis([-1,axx_max+1,-1,axy_max+1])
plt.xlabel('Data set')
plt.ylabel('Average distance travelled')
plt.title('There are %s source(s) with %s valid' % (source_count,len(source_distance)))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(1, average, s=10, c='b', marker="+", label='First timestep')
 #ax1.scatter(x[40:],y[40:], s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='second')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');

plt.show()

 # NOTES AND REMOVED CODE

 # Move sources around over time
 # -> keep within a fixed range of motion
 # -> randomly generate motion

 # Calculate motion of sources from images
 # -> ignore direction
 # -> all that move by same magnitude get stored together
 # -> Number of sources against magnitude of motion

 # Make dictionary of number of sources that have moved a certain amount. 
 #source_motion_count = {} # make length of sources, values all 0
 #for elem in range(len(source_distance)):
 #  if type(source_distance[elem])!=str and source_distance[elem]>-1:
 #      source_motion_count[source_distance[elem]] = 0

 #for elem in range(len(source_distance)):
 #  if type(source_distance[elem])!=str and source_distance[elem]>-1:
 #      source_motion_count[source_distance[elem]] += 1

 # Compile count of sources based on movement into graph

 #number_of_sources = []
 #distance_travelled = []

 #for n in range(len(source_motion_count)):
 #  key=source_motion_count.keys()[n]
 #  number_of_sources.append(source_motion_count[key])
 #  distance_travelled.append(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by turning that section into its own function. I also changed my mind on some of what I wanted it to do, so there is a little variation from the original idea to what is below.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import copy
import random
from pylab import boxplot

#------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#--------------------------FUNCTIONS-------------------------------------#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------#

def original_image():
    # create image
    original_positions = np.random.randint(2,size=(11,11))
    # make sure image has uneven lengths - will be useful later
    y = original_positions.shape[0]
    x = original_positions.shape[1]
    if y%2 == 0:
        y-=1

    if x%2 == 0:
        x-=1

    original_positions = original_positions[0:y,0:x]
    return original_positions

def random_movement(source_positions):
    source_positions_changed={}
    # create some random movement in x and y axis, within a certain range
    for n in range(len(source_positions)):
        key = source_positions.keys()[n] # original source positions
        del_x = source_positions[key][0]+random.randint(-1,1)
        del_y = source_positions[key][1]+random.randint(-1,1)
        source_positions_changed[key] = (del_x,del_y)
    return source_positions_changed

def tag_sources(original_positions):
    source_positions = {}
    source_count=0
    # keeping track of all the sources (1's) from original image
    for x in range(len(original_positions)):
        for y in range(len(original_positions[0])):
            if original_positions[x,y] == 1: # finding all sources
                source_count += 1
                index = 'S'+str(source_count)
                source_positions[index] = (x,y) 
    return source_positions

def calc_motion(position_dict_changed, position_dict_original,xaxis_len,yaxis_len):
    position_dict_motion = {}
    for source_num in range(1,len(position_dict_original)+1):
        # make sources that go outside the image range -1
        if position_dict_changed['S{0}'.format(source_num)][1]>=yaxis_len or position_dict_changed['S{0}'.format(source_num)][0]>=xaxis_len:
            position_dict_motion['S{0}'.format(source_num)] = -1
        else:
            # determine x and y motion from original position
            # this is the main difference from the original idea as do not want to average the motion
            x_motion = position_dict_original['S{0}'.format(source_num)][1] - position_dict_changed['S{0}'.format(source_num)][1]
            y_motion = position_dict_original['S{0}'.format(source_num)][0] - position_dict_changed['S{0}'.format(source_num)][0]
            position_dict_motion['S{0}'.format(source_num)] = (y_motion,x_motion)
    return position_dict_motion

#------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#--------------------------OTHER CODE------------------------------------#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# creating random distribution of sources
original_positions = original_image()

orig_xaxis_len = len(original_positions[0])
orig_yaxis_len = len(original_positions)

# tag sources in original_positions
source_positions = tag_sources(original_positions)

source_numbers = len(source_positions)
# how many images were taken NOT including the original
number_timesteps = 2 

# create a dictionary for the timesteps of shifted sources
positions_dict = {}
for x in range(1,number_timesteps+1):
    positions_dict['position_changed{0}'.format(x)] = copy.copy(random_movement(source_positions))

# create a dictionary of the motion from the original position for each image
for x in range(1,number_timesteps+1):
    motion_dict['position_changed{0}'.format(x)] = copy.copy(calc_motion(positions_dict['position_changed{0}'.format(x)],source_positions,orig_xaxis_len,orig_yaxis_len))


print motion_dict
```